# edX numerical input error "Sorry couldn't parse formula" when using inequalities

Tags: xml, edx-studio

I am trying to create a question on edX Studio where the answer is an inequality. As far as I understand edX used the Mathjax library for which `\ge` or `&ge;` represent the ≥ symbol.
I can use `\ge` in the question and it is displayed properly.

```
<p>Enter the inequality \[x \ge 1\]: </p>
```

displays:

Enter the inequality x ≥ 1:

There is a text box input field and a `MathJax_Display` div to display the formula.
I would expect that the input fiel would accept `>` or `<` etc. but it doesn't, nor does it accept html/xml entities or MathJax macros.
If I type `x > 1`, `x \ge 1` or `x &ge; 1` in the input field the formula display shows "Sorry couldn't parse formula"
Is there a way that I can get the input field to accept an inequality symbol that the `MathJax_Display` div will be able to parse?